# How to add 'px' to calc function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have the following:

```
style={{ width: 'calc(100% - 300px)' }}
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
let myWidth: number = 300;
 style={{ width: 'calc(100% - {myWidth})' }}
```

Above example fails, how do I accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `myWidth` to a string like so: `let myWidth = '300px';`

Try the snippet below or see this [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/pWjWeJ)

```js
const App = () => {
  let myWidth = "300px";
  return (
    <div className="full">
      <div className="inner" style={{ width: `calc(100% - ${myWidth})` }}>
        Hi
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

// log .inner div style
console.log(document.querySelector(".inner").style.width);
```

```css
.full {
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 100vw;
}

.inner {
  background: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use template string:

```
const myWidth: number = 300;
style = {{ width: `calc(100% - ${myWidth}px)` }}
```

Comment: check with 'px' after variable

Comment: looks like it's not accepting ${myWidth} as a string literal, the result of that string ends up being calc(100% - $myWidth}px)'

Comment: @tweetypi probobly you are missing a `{`